# Database design store old versions mysql

Tags: mysql, database, logging, database-design

I have a big database in mysql. And in some tables I want to store old versions of rows. Also I need to store old values in some related tables. Can anyone show me a such database design samples which will work in any case? 
[image]

This is Sample from my db. Here I want to store all changes which will be made to university.

Comment: Your question seems to be too broad, could you specifiy what you want more and change the question accordingly?

Comment: I added sample from db

Comment: You're describing [history tables](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/07/history-tables.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any table to a versioned or temporal table. You select which columns of which tables to version. History is maintained automagically and within the entity tables. Complete details are too long for here, but [this](http://www.slideshare.net/TommCarr/bitemporal-rdbms-2014) is a slide presentation that should explain everything, table design, views and triggers -- or enough to perform an evaluation to see if it meets your needs.